# simple sms payment system

Tags: java, netbeans, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use output from a splited sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351910/how-to-use-output-from-a-splited-sms)

I have code to read the text messages using smslib. I want to develop an sms payment system using Java. I have a database with two tables Personal account and merchant account. The procedure is like, text a message like `pay*merchant*amount`. Now I need to know how to split the text but the problem is on how to use the variables which have been splitted. I mean for example take the amount and deduct it in the personal account whilst increasing the merchants account. If the you know the queries required please tell me and the required coding.

Here is the code lam using for splitting

```
 String myString =  (msg.getText());

 String[] a = myString.split("\\*");

    for (String b : a) {

          System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: OK, stop this already.  What is your **specific question**? You've posted the same question like 4 times now!  We are **not** going to **do your coding for you**.  Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325944/sms-payment-system, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329692/use-of-actions-in-sms, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351910/how-to-use-output-from-a-splited-sms